# php5-geoip performance issue

Tags: php5, geolocation, geoip

I installed the php5-geoip module on Ubuntu 10.04 via `apt-get install php5-geoip`. I've updated the `geocities.dat` library

The production server performance decreased and load average is soaring. Before the install it was less than 1 for the same traffic level. I suspect  that the geoip data is not memory cached.

How can I activate memory caching for this module?

Comment: Update: the server load remains high even if the code doesnt actually use the geoip functions. The linking of the geoip lib into php cause it. Still puzzled and looking for the way to solve it